# Unable to Navigate to other component page in angular 10

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am building a sample project named : **Tennis Club Management** using Angular 10. In this i have **app component** and **dashboard component**. In **app.component.html**, i have created login which takes 2 inputs **username** and **password** and contains **login button**. Now on login button click , it should validate the fields and navigate it to **dashboard.html**.

**Below are the code files and screenshots**

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="backgroundDiv">
<!--  <div>-->
<!--    <img class="img-fluid backgroundimage" src="https://rrtennis.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Restyled-Logo-2-SD-small.png" alt="Tennis Logo">-->
<!--  </div>-->
  <div class="text-center">
    <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="https://rrtennis.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Restyled-Logo-2-SD-small.png" alt="Tennis Logo">
    <div class="text-center">
      <table class="table table-borderless">
        <tr><h6>Admin Login</h6></tr>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-xs-5">Username</th>
          <td class="col-xs-5"><input type="text" #username></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-xs-5">Password</th>
          <td class="col-xs-5"><input type="password" #password></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-5"><button  class="btn btn-primary" (click)="validateLogin(username.value,password.value)">Login</button></td>
          <td class="col-xs-5"><label class="forgot-password">Forgot Password ?</label></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!--  https://www.usta.com/content/dam/usta/Articles/article-primary/18309_C_NY_20_USTA_ZoomBackgroundsVisitOrlando_3.jpg  -->
<!--  https://i.pinimg.com/originals/81/23/d4/8123d454ca0cc8f36d311cebbd5d3922.png  -->
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tennis-Angular';

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
  validateLogin(username: string, password: string) {
    if (username === 'mohit' && password === 'sharma') {
      // alert('Login Successful !');
      this.router.navigate(['../dashboard']);
    } else if (username === '' && password === '') {
      alert('Email and Password cannot be blank !');
    } else if (username === '') {
      alert('Email cannot be blank !');
    } else if (password === '') {
      alert('Password cannot be blank !');
    } else {
      alert('Incorrect Email or Password !');
    }
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        NgbModule,
        FormsModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.css**

```
.backgroundDiv {
  background: url('https://www.usta.com/content/dam/usta/Articles/article-primary/18309_C_NY_20_USTA_ZoomBackgroundsVisitOrlando_3.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.80;
}

.table {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: white;
  /*margin-top: 15%;*/
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-primary {
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.forgot-password {
  margin-top: 8%;
}

img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 50%;
  max-width: 25%;
  height: auto;
}

tbody {
  background-color: white;
}

h6 {
  margin-left: 100%;
  width: 150%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  color: mediumseagreen;
  text-shadow: mediumseagreen;
}
```

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<p>dashboard works!</p>
```

**Screenshots**

**Home Page Login**

[image: Login Page]

[image: After Login]

**Note :** The problem is after login , the **URL** shows the navigation route(path), but the page is not getting displayed. **Any solution please ?**

Comment: Add <router-outlet> in app component where you want to render your dashboard component. As kishore suggested better approach would be creating a seprate component for login and keep app.component.html file clean only with router-outlet.

Comment: Abhijeet Raj: thanks brother for your help.. have a great day.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in you app.component.html.

I would suggest create a login component and move your app component code to login component and have  alone on your app.component.html.

So whenever you change route your previous component HTML won't render.

Comment: Kishore : thanks brother for your help...have a great day....